# How to update one Javascript object array without updating the other

Tags: javascript, arrays

I created an object array with some values. Then I created another object array and initialized it with the first one. Then I pushed a value in 2nd array, and console logged both arrays. Both arrays had same value. Why is this happening and how can we stop this?

My Code:

```
var a = { "filters": [] }; // 1st object array
var keyValue = {};
// pushed 2 values in "a" array
keyValue["abc"] = "123";
a.filters.push(keyValue);
keyValue["def"] = "456";
a.filters.push(keyValue);
var b = a; // created another object array & initialized it with "a" array
var keyValue1 = {};
// pushed 1 value in "b" array
keyValue1["ghi"] = "789";
b.filters.push(keyValue1);
console.log(a);
console.log(b);
```

This prints same values for a and b.
How do I push values into 2nd array without updating 1st one?

Comment: this is related to *object cloning*, try searching for that.

Comment: This post also might be relevant in explaining how objects are handled and how to copy them elegantly in javascript - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/728360/most-elegant-way-to-clone-a-javascript-object

Answer (score 1):

Assignment such as `var b = a` for a object creates an object 'b' which references(just like pointer) the same location pointed by 'a', in general. You may find this [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var) helpful.

However you can create/clone a new array with **slice** method. `var b = a.slice()`

Comment: will slice method not update "a" array if "b" is updated.??

Comment: `a` is an object, not array. So you can't use `slice`.

Comment: no.. with this b will be new array and no way related to a.

Answer (score 0):

Both are pointing to the same values in the memory when you say:

```
var b = a;
```

So if you change a, b will be affected and vice versa, you need to copy using a loop.

**EDIT**

use this line of code which I get from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7486085/copying-array-by-value-in-javascript)

```
var b= a.slice(0);
```

Comment: could you share apiece of code on how to clone "a" array to "b"

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
var b = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(a));
```

https://stackoverflow.com/a/4591639/1623259

Comment: will it not update "a" array if "b" is updated.??

Comment: no, it will not update because 'b' is a new object in the memory.